# Command to find domain name from IP address

Tags: windows, dns

I have a website with dedicated IP address. Currently it is: **184.154.225.69**

If I do nslookup this IP, I get **placeholder.sgded.com** as output name. But I want to get my domain name, exactly how I get on sites like:
[ip2hosts.com](http://www.ip2hosts.com/)

What command can I execute to get this output?

Comment: Dedicated IP address doesn't mean domain name. You need to buy domain name and attach to your dedicated IP. `placeholder.sgded.com` is a temporary name which you got with your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse DNS is maintained by the network who provide the IP address - you may be able to speak to them nicely, and request they change the PTR record to what you'd like it to be.

What that website is probably doing, is connecting to the default website, and following any redirects and/or checking how the server identifies itself (in this case, via the certificate the HTTPS server identifies with). Had there been no web server, that service could not work, nor could it work if the IP address hosted many websites (for example, for 83.136.68.48 there are many websites that it does not list).

Comment: The problem is that the website posted as example, gives me the correct value. And I'm wondering how that's made.

Comment: I don't believe they are connecting to the website, as then they would always have only a single result, while services such as http://www.ip2hosts.com are especially useful to get a (partial) list of domains hosted on the same server.